# Android Insert Intent Calendar Event Not Trigger startActivityForResult or ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-contentresolver, android-calendar

I want to add a calendar event with intent. The code below does this successfully.

```
val startMillis: Long = Calendar.getInstance().run {
    set(2012, 0, 19, 7, 30)
    timeInMillis
}
val endMillis: Long = Calendar.getInstance().run {
    set(2012, 0, 19, 8, 30)
    timeInMillis
}
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startMillis)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endMillis)
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
        .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY, CalendarContract.Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "rowan@example.com,trevor@example.com")
startActivity(intent)
```

But I need the id of the calendar event added afterwards.
I used a **registerContentObserver** for this. So **registerContentObserver** is triggered when an event is registered. Then I consider the last added calendar event as the event I added with intent. But **registerContentObserver** takes a long time like 4 seconds to trigger.

I can't catch this with **startActivityForResult** or new method **ActivityResultLauncher**. Is there a method to this?

Comment: "I can't catch this with startActivityForResult or new method ActivityResultLauncher" -- you should get a `Uri` back via those mechanisms, according to [the `ACTION_INSERT` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=en#ACTION_INSERT). You should be able to query the provider to get the ID using that `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare  If I insert with ContentProvider, I can get the id because the uri is returned. But if I do that, I will have to organize a calendar add activity. Instead I want to use the system's calendar activity. Is there a way around this?

Comment: "Instead I want to use the system's calendar activity" -- your code in your question is starting an `ACTION_INSERT` activity. According to [the `ACTION_INSERT` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=en#ACTION_INSERT), you should get a `Uri` as output, via `onActivityResult()` or the equivalent with an `ActivityResultLauncher`. You may wish to update your [mcve] to show how you tried using `startActivityForResult()` or `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult`.